# ReactJs - SPA Navbar

Tags: html, css, reactjs

### Problem

So I am working to create a Single Page Application with `ReactJs`but I am having an issues with my Navbar. I cannot seem to get the nav buttons to link to the pages correctly without reloading the webpage instead of updating the rendered component.

When I attempt the following:
`<NavItem eventKey={1} href="/someLink">someLink</NavItem>`

I find that clicking the corresponding Nav button will reload the page with the correct expected content instead of only updating the rendered component.

When I attempt the following:
`<NavItem eventKey={1}><NavLink to="/someLink">someLink</NavLink></NavItem>`

I find that the link will load the page IF I click directly on the link text itself, but will update the rendered component without reloading the whole page. The same results are seen if I switch `NavLink` for `Link`.

When I attempt the following: 
`<NavItem eventKey={1} href="/someLink"><NavLink to="/someLink">someLink</NavLink></NavItem>`

I find that the text link will update the rendered component, but if I click on any of the space around the text, but still inside the same button, it will take me to the correct page, but will reload the entire page. Like above, I have seen the same results from switching `NavLink` for `Link`

If it helps, this is the code I am working with:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Navbar, Nav, NavItem, MenuItem, NavDropdown } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link, NavLink } from "react-router-dom";
import { getUserGroup } from './Auth.jsx';

/* All page imports */
import Home from '../pages/Home';
import PackageQuery from '../pages/PkgQuery';
import CustQuery from '../pages/CustomerQuery';
import CustUpdate from '../pages/CustUpdate';
import PackageReports from '../pages/PkgReports';
import IntlReports from '../pages/IntlReports';
import SalesReports from '../pages/SalesReports';

const isDev = getUserGroup() === "dev" ? true : false;
const isAdmin = getUserGroup() === "admin" ? true : false;
const isDataAnalyst = getUserGroup() === "analyst" ? true : false;

/*
*  Below is an example of conditional rendering
*  Using the above variables as shorthand, each "render" performs a check against the user role
*  to determine if the navigation bar should render that piece of the navigation component.
*  The final navbar pushed to the component that utilizes the Navigation componenet will never
*  know the existance of the non-rendered pieces, helping to prevent potential security issues
*/
export default class Navigation extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <div>
          <Navbar fluid collapseOnSelect>
            <Navbar.Header>
              <Navbar.Brand>
                <NavLink to="/"> HOME </NavLink>
              </Navbar.Brand>
            </Navbar.Header>
              <Nav bsStyle="tabs" >
                <NavDropdown eventKey={1} title="QUERIES" id="query-nav-dropdown">
                  {!isDataAnalyst ? <MenuItem eventKey={1.1}><NavLink to="/PkgQuery">PACKAGE QUERY</NavLink></MenuItem> : null}
                  <MenuItem eventKey={1.2}><NavLink to="/CustQuery">CUSTOMER QUERY</NavLink></MenuItem>
                </NavDropdown>
                {isDev || isAdmin ? <NavItem eventKey={2} href="/CustUpdate"><NavLink to="/CustUpdate">UPDATE CUSTOMER DATA</NavLink></NavItem> : null}
                {isDev || isAdmin || isDataAnalyst ? <NavDropdown eventKey={5} title="REPORTS" id="reports-nav-dropdown">
                  {isDev || isAdmin || isDataAnalyst ? <MenuItem eventKey={5.1}><NavLink to="/PkgReports">PACKAGE REPORTS</NavLink></MenuItem> : null}
                  {isDev || isAdmin || isDataAnalyst ? <MenuItem eventKey={5.2}><NavLink to="/IntlReports">INTERNATIONAL REPORTS</NavLink></MenuItem> : null}
                  {isDev || isAdmin || isDataAnalyst ? <MenuItem eventKey={5.3}><NavLink to="/SalesReports">SALES REPORTS</NavLink></MenuItem> : null}
                </NavDropdown> : null}
                <NavItem eventKey={7} to="/Help">HELP</NavItem>
                <NavItem eventKey={8}><NavLink to="/logout">LOGOUT</NavLink></NavItem>
              </Nav>
          </Navbar>

          <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
          <Route path="/PkgQuery" component={PkgQuery} />
          <Route path="/CustQuery" component={CustQuery} />
          <Route path="/CustUpdate" component={CustUpdate} />
          <Route path="/PkgReports" component={PkgReports} />
          <Route path="/IntlReports" component={IntlReports} />
          <Route path="/SalesReports" component={SalesReports} />
        </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}
```

### Question

Does anyone know the proper way to utilize `Nav`, `NavLink`, `Link`, and/or `NavItem` to ensure only the target component updates instead of the whole page from reloading?

### Answer

This answer was achieved with the help of @zaunermax

The base answer is to get `react-router-bootstrap` and utilize its `LinkContainer` component to modifiy the code.

To modify the code, it was simply about removing the `Link` and/or `NavLink` components and wrapping the `NavItem` and `MenuItem` tags inside the `LinkContainer` tag like so:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Navbar, Nav, NavItem, MenuItem, NavDropdown } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link, NavLink } from "react-router-dom";
import { LinkContainer } from 'react-router-bootstrap';
import { getUserGroup } from './Auth.jsx';

/* All page imports */
import Home from '../pages/Home';
import PackageQuery from '../pages/PkgQuery';
import CustQuery from '../pages/CustomerQuery';
import CustUpdate from '../pages/CustUpdate';
import PackageReports from '../pages/PkgReports';
import IntlReports from '../pages/IntlReports';
import SalesReports from '../pages/SalesReports';

const isDev = getUserGroup() === "dev" ? true : false;
const isAdmin = getUserGroup() === "admin" ? true : false;
const isDataAnalyst = getUserGroup() === "analyst" ? true : false;

/*
*  Below is an example of conditional rendering
*  Using the above variables as shorthand, each "render" performs a check against the user role
*  to determine if the navigation bar should render that piece of the navigation component.
*  The final navbar pushed to the component that utilizes the Navigation componenet will never
*  know the existance of the non-rendered pieces, helping to prevent potential security issues
*/
export default class Navigation extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <div>
          <Navbar fluid collapseOnSelect>
            <Navbar.Header>
              <Navbar.Brand>
                <NavLink to="/"> HOME </NavLink>
              </Navbar.Brand>
            </Navbar.Header>
              <Nav bsStyle="tabs" >
                <NavDropdown eventKey={1} title="QUERIES" id="query-nav-dropdown">
                  {!isDataAnalyst ? <LinkContainer to="/PkgQuery"><MenuItem eventKey={1.1}>PACKAGE QUERY</MenuItem></LinkContainer> : null}
                  <LinkContainer to="/CustQuery"><MenuItem eventKey={1.2}>CUSTOMER QUERY</MenuItem></LinkContainer>
                </NavDropdown>
                {isDev || isAdmin ? <LinkContainer to="/CustQuery"><NavItem eventKey={2} href="/CustUpdate"><NavLink to="/CustUpdate">UPDATE CUSTOMER DATA</NavLink></NavItem> : null}
                {isDev || isAdmin || isDataAnalyst ? <NavDropdown eventKey={5} title="REPORTS" id="reports-nav-dropdown">
                  {isDev || isAdmin || isDataAnalyst ? <LinkContainer to="/PkgReports"><MenuItem eventKey={5.1}>PACKAGE REPORTS</MenuItem></LinkContainer> : null}
                  {isDev || isAdmin || isDataAnalyst ? <LinkContainer to="/IntlReports"><MenuItem eventKey={5.2}>INTERNATIONAL REPORTS</MenuItem></LinkContainer> : null}
                  {isDev || isAdmin || isDataAnalyst ? <LinkContainer to="/SalesReports"><MenuItem eventKey={5.3}>SALES REPORTS</MenuItem></LinkContainer> : null}
                </NavDropdown> : null}
                <NavItem eventKey={7} to="/Help">HELP</NavItem>
                <NavItem eventKey={8}><NavLink to="/logout">LOGOUT</NavLink></NavItem>
              </Nav>
          </Navbar>

          <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
          <Route path="/PkgQuery" component={PkgQuery} />
          <Route path="/CustQuery" component={CustQuery} />
          <Route path="/CustUpdate" component={CustUpdate} />
          <Route path="/PkgReports" component={PkgReports} />
          <Route path="/IntlReports" component={IntlReports} />
          <Route path="/SalesReports" component={SalesReports} />
        </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Writing this as an answer because of lacking rep.

You might consider using [react-router-bootstrap](https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-router-bootstrap) as it combines react-bootstrap and react-router so your page is not reloaded every time you click on the wrong link.

Comment: I don't seem to be understanding how to use this. Looking at the notes in the link, it talks about wrapping a piece inside of `LinkContainer`; however, I don't seem to be achieving the results I want. Could I trouble you with updating your answer with some examples to help understand how to use this?

Comment: It took a lot of playing around, but I figured it out. This did in fact lead me to the answer. For anyone interested, I have updated my post to include the answer